# How can I list all files except .tar in solaris 11

Tags: bash, list, file

Can you provide equivalent of following command in solaris 11

```
ls /export/!(*.tar)
```

Comment: This does not look like a bash command to me

Comment: @GabrielDevillers It is: extended glob pattern, see the "extglob" paragraph: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching

Comment: Apparently, the default shell for Solaris 11 is ksh93, and [it seems to support this pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh-1.html).

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, I realize I have to learn more about my shell

Answer (score 0):

How about using `find`? Something like:

```
$ find /export -type f ! -name "*.tar" -ls
```

**Note 1** Remove `-ls` to get more compact output
**Note 2** To do not go into subdirectories, explore [this hint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18321/solaris-equivalent-for-depth-prune).

I hope it will help,
Jarek